# I want to open an app inside another app with android intent plus

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to open an app inside another app with android intent plus but i get error.colud you help me
please?

this is error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=package: (has extras) }, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=package: (has extras) }
```

```
Future<void> openMyApp() async {
  if (const LocalPlatform().isAndroid) {
    const AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: 'action_view',
      data: 'package:com.example.super_app',
      arguments: {'authAccount': "1234@gmail.com"},
    );
    await intent.launch();
  }
}
```

I used the function  above but I got error.

Answer (score 0):

base on your error, it says that it cant find an activity to handle the intent.

its case sensitive. try updating your code to this:

also i see that you made errors on package also update that.

```
Future<void> openMyApp() async {
      if (const LocalPlatform().isAndroid) {
        const AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
          action: 'android.intent.action.VIEW', 
          package: 'com.example.super_app', 
          arguments: {'authAccount': "1234@gmail.com"},
        );
        await intent.launch();
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks.this codes gets no error but it doesnt open the app.it opens a bottomsheet that suggests some apps to open the destination app.I want it to get open directly.is it possible?